# Can I train the fine tuned model on combined ( train+dev) sets and then evaluate with test set?

Tags: keras, deep-learning

The data set i'm working with  consists of train and test sets. To fine tune the deep learning model, 10% of training set is used as validation set. After finding the optimal hyper parameter values, two possible options are

a) Evaluate the model (i.e., the model which is trained on 90 % of train set) with test set

b) Evaluate the model (i.e., the model retrained on complete train set) with test set

Which is of the above options is valid? and why?

Answer (score 0):

Both options are possible,
But in the First case the HPP are optimal, in the second case they are usually close to the optimal hyper parameters (but not optimal), but you have a more representative dataset

What is suggested in general is to do a CrossValidation https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html -> choose different train/test to have a more representative case, and choose the best HPP base on **an average on the values for each folds**

Because, what you risk is, your model would be very good for this specific case **as you can have for Kaggle datasets**, but maybe not representative of real use cases once in production.

To sum up:
1. If you just want the best model for this set, maybe option 1 is safest (option 2 can be done too, but you may have worse results)
2. If you are in a **"real case study"**, you should better do cross-validation to have more robust set of HPPs